# Cannot connect to wmi provider sql server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012, wmi, sql-server-agent, sql-server-config-manager

The following error dialog pops up when I tried connecting to SQL Server Configuration Manager on my SQL Server 2012 production server:

> Cannot connect to WMI provider. You do not have permission or the server is unreachable. Note that you can only manage SQL Server 2005 and later servers with SQL Server Configuration Manager. Invalid class [0x800700c1]

I've executed the following `mofcomp` command in command prompt to re-register the `*.mof` files:

```
mofcomp.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Shared\sqlmgmproviderxpsp2up.mof"
```

The command was executed successfully, but I still have the same problem !

Thanks

Comment: Did you restart WMI? 
net stop winmgmt
net start winmgmt

Answer (score 0):

Your directory is wrong (or you don't actually have SQL Server 2012).  According to [KB956013](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/956013), if you're using SQL Server 2012, you need to be accessing the "110" folder.  You are referencing the "100" folder.

Try this:

```
mofcomp.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Shared\sqlmgmproviderxpsp2up.mof"
```

and as Louie pointed out, don't forget to restart the WMI service.